# Custom List View didn't show item

Tags: php, android

I rewrite some code from internet, when i try it the listview didn't show anything just a blank activity
Here is the code :

Adapter.java :

```
public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<DataAnggota> items;

    public Adapter(Activity activity, List<DataAnggota> items) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return items.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_user_list, null);

        TextView id = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.id);
        TextView nama = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nama);
        TextView status = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.status);

        DataAnggota data = items.get(position);

        id.setText(data.getId_anggota());
        nama.setText(data.getNama());
        status.setText(data.getStatus());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

ViewUser.java

```
public class ViewUser extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView list;
    List<DataAnggota> itemList = new ArrayList<DataAnggota>();
    Adapter adapter;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    String url_viewuser = "http://10.0.2.2/test/viewuser.php";
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_user);

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        adapter = new Adapter(ViewUser.this, itemList);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        callVolley();

    }
    private void callVolley(){
        itemList.clear();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        // membuat request JSON
        JsonArrayRequest jArr = new JsonArrayRequest(url_viewuser, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);

                        DataAnggota item = new DataAnggota();

                        item.setId_anggota(obj.getString("id_anggota"));
                        item.setNama(obj.getString("nama"));
                        item.setStatus(obj.getString("status"));
                        itemList.add(item);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            }
        });
        AppController.getInstance(ViewUser.this).addToRequestQueue(jArr);
    }

}
```

activity_view_user.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_view_user"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.rzproject.koperasi.ViewUser">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"></ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

view_user_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/id"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/nama"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/status"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

viewuser.php

```
include "init.php";

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM anggota ORDER BY id_anggota ASC");

    $json = array();

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $json[] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode($json);

    mysql_close($con);
```

any code wrong ? please help

Comment: Try setting the adapter after you fill your ArrayList. Currently you are setting it with an empty array and you are updating the local arraylist and not the arraylist used in the listview.

Comment: @JordiSipkens can u give me some solution ? i try to move callVolley method but some still empty and some make my app force closed

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_user);

    callVolley();
}

private void setupList(){
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    adapter = new Adapter(ViewUser.this, itemList);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void callVolley(){
    itemList.clear();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    // membuat request JSON
    JsonArrayRequest jArr = new JsonArrayRequest(url_viewuser, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);

                    DataAnggota item = new DataAnggota();

                    item.setId_anggota(obj.getString("id_anggota"));
                    item.setNama(obj.getString("nama"));
                    item.setStatus(obj.getString("status"));
                    itemList.add(item);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            setupList();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
        }
    });
    AppController.getInstance(ViewUser.this).addToRequestQueue(jArr);
}
```

Hope this is clear enough. First load your data, after loading it just set the listview + adapter.

If you want to change the data AGAIN, just make a method in the adapter to set the listview, and then call the notifydatasetchanged method. This way you update the list inside the adapter and then tell the listview to redraw itself.